# Replacing values in an association based on keys

Tags: associations

Let's say I have the association

```
assoc = <|"random1" -> {a,b,c}, "random11" -> {b}|>
```

I want to replace the values, based on something related to the keys. For example, the values should be based on the number of digits in the corresponding key or the length of the key. If it's based on number of digits in the key, the final assoc would be:

```
assoc = <|"random1" -> {1}, "random11" -> {2}|>
```

If it's based on the stringlength then it would be:

```
assoc = <|"random1" -> {7}, "random11" -> {8}|>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: See [`KeyValueMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html). Or if you want to build a new `Association` based purely on key values see [`AssociationMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationMap.html) and do `AssociationMap[f,Keys[a]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was messing around with `Keyvaluemap` but I couldn't get it done. `AssociationMap` did what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the comments by b3m2a1, replacing the values with length of keys for example can be achieved by:

```
AssociationMap[StringLength, Keys[assoc]]
```